# Qt and C++ how to convert Obj& to Obj*

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

I am new to Qt ( and C++ in general), so I am pretty weak at pointers. I need to convert `Object&` to `Object*` ( where `Object` is an object of some class )

How do I do it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In which context? In a function call?

Comment: Its in a function definition, but I asked in general nevertheless

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Obj ob;              <-------  Object named ob of the type Obj
Obj *ptr = &ob;      <-------  Oointer named ptr to type Obj pointing to ob    
Obj &ref = *ptr;     <-------- Reference named ref referring to object of type Obj  
Obj *ptr2 = &ref;    <-------- Pointer named ptr2 to object aliased by ref
```

You cannot convert a reference to a pointer, you just use an reference as an alias name to the object instance it refers to. Thus you simply take the address of the referenced object, just as if it were the original object.

So if you have a function which takes a pointer as argument and you have an reference you pass the usage is similar to that of using an actual object.

For example:

```
void doSomething(Obj *ptr);

Obj ob;
Obj *ptr = &ob;              
Obj &ref = *ptr; 

doSomething(&ob);
doSomething(ptr);
doSomething(&ref);
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped ! I was getting the error since some time but now its solved.

Answer (score 1):

You use the address-of operator, just like for a plain object.

```
SomeObject o;

SomeObject &ref = o;

SomeObject *ptr = &ref;
```

Comment: Yes, same as what @als told ( although may be it was you who posted earlier :D ).